# How do you create a vector of linked lists in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I declared a vector of linked list (and the linked lists hold `int` values). Then I tried to push a value onto the linked list (`i` is just a position in the vector):

```
vector< list<int> > linkedListVector;
adjacencyVector[i].push_back(s);
```

The problem is that I run into a segmentation fault when I run the above command and I don't know why. I looked up the C++ documentation and my formatting looks correct. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the vector's size? Is it at least i+1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a for loop then you probably already know what the max size will be so you can just use the `resize` method like this:

```
adjacencyVector.resize(MAXSIZE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The vector starts out with a size of zero, and you must create the vector element before pushing onto the list at `[i]`.

If your `i` progresses in a normal fashion, you could `push_back()` onto the vector first, then onto the list in the vector.  If not you could add something a bit ugly such as:

```
if ( adjacencyVector.size() <= i ) { adjacencyVector.resize(i + 1) ; }
adjacencyVector[i].push_back(s);
```

Comment: Can you expand on how I would do that? My vector doesn't have a fixed size and I'm using a loop to push the correct values.

Comment: Or you can `resize` or `reserve`.

Comment: @erip: `reserve()` will not create the actual `list` objects, but `resize()` will.

Comment: I tried doing this `vector< list<int> > linkedListVector (0, maxSize);` and it gave me an error that I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an instance of `list<int>` to the `vector` before you can then access a specific `list<int>` by index, then you can call `push_back()` on the `list<int>`.  So either `push_back()` a `list<int>` into the vector:

```
vector< list<int> > adjacencyVector;

list<int> l;
adjacencyVector.push_back(l);
...
adjacencyVector[0].push_back(s);
```

Or call the vector's `resize()` method to add multiple lists at one time:

```
vector< list<int> > adjacencyVector;

adjacencyVector.resize(number of lists);
...
adjacencyVector[index].push_back(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then I tried to push a value onto the linked list.

You tried to access an object, which didn't exist. The adjacencyVector[i] list does not exist as adjacencyVector is an empty vector if you did not put an element into it.

The following example will make some details clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::list<int> > v; // This statement creates an empty vector of lists of integers.
    std::list<int> l; // This statement creates an empty list of integers.
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
        l.push_back(i);
        v.push_back(l);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i){ // You can access elements calling the operator[].
        for(std::list<int>::iterator it=v[i].begin(); it!=v[i].end(); ++it){
            std::cout<<*it<<' '; // You can access elements calling the operator[] , you need an iterator.
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    //std::cout<<*(v[v.size()].begin())<<std::endl; // It causes segmentation fault, because v[10] does not exist,
                                                  // 10 is out of range of valid indexes.
}
```

Vectors and lists are quit similar. Inserting and deleting are more effective if you use list, but accessing an element is usually more effective if you use vector.